# Checking my proof of this inequality (Coding Theory)

Tags: solution-verification, coding-theory

I'm working on proving this inequality regarding the weights of code words.

$w(x+y) \leq wt(x) + wt(y)$

I've been thinking about it for a little bit and the first idea I came up with was kind of long. I was doing a proof by cases: one where $x = y$ and there other where $x \neq y$.

Proof:

Case 1: For two code words $x,y$, if $x = y$, then $x + y = 0$. Thus $wt(x+y) = 0$. As $0 \leq wt(x)$ and $0 \leq wt(y)$, adding these two inequalities gives us $0 \leq wt(x) + wt(y)$. Yielding $wt(x+y) \leq wt(x) + wt(y)$.

Case 2: For two code words $x,y$. Assume $x \neq y$. Once again we add the inequalities $0 \leq wt(x)$ and $0 \leq wt(y)$, resulting in $0 \leq wt(x) + wt(y)$. Adding $wt(x+y)$ to both sides, we have $wt(x+y) \leq wt(x) + wt(y) + wt(x+y)$. From this, it is clear that $wt(x) + wt(y) \leq wt(x) + wt(y) + wt(x+y)$. Thus $wt(x+y) \leq wt(x) + wt(y) \leq wt(x) + wt(y) + wt(x+y)$.

The more I look at this, the more I think that the use of cases is unnecessary. I'm pretty sure the second case holds whether $x$ and $y$ are equal or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the case $1$ is fine. The second case I do not understand what you are doing. So, you start with $0\leq w(x)$ and $0\leq w(y)$ concluding that $0\leq w(x)+w(y)$. This is fine. Now, you add $w(x+y)$ and you get
$$w(x+y)\leq w(x)+w(y)+w(x+y)$$
which is also fine. But then you argue that because $w(x+y)\leq w(x)+w(y)+w(x+y)$ and $w(x)+w(y)\leq w(x)+w(y)+w(x+y)$ then $w(x+y)\leq w(x)+w(y)$ and this is not correct. You cannot infer from $A\leq C$ and $B\leq C$ anything about how $A$ and $B$ are ordered.
Now, i guess you are dealing with a binary code from the $2x=0$, so think of $w(x+y)$ as the cardinal of the indices in which the code is not equal to zero. Partition the set in such a way that $w(x)$ and $w(y)$ appear as cardinals also.

Comment: I think I might have come up with a better argument: I have the equality that $wt(x+y) = wt(x) + wt(y) - 2wt(x \cap y)$ ( $x \cap y$ denotes vector multiplication in this context). This implies that $wt(x+y) + 2wt(x \cap y) = wt(x) + wt(y)$. So as $0 \leq wt(x + y)$ and $ 0 \leq 2wt(x \cap y)$, we can argue that $wt(x + y)  \leq wt(x+y) + 2wt(x \cap y)$ or in other words $wt(x + y) \leq wt(x) + wt(y)$.

Comment: @UnderMathUate Yes! I do agree with this one better.

Comment: Ok, awesome. Thank you for the feedback!